# How can I create an Adobe extension

Tags: dreamweaver

I'm using an adobe extension for Dreamweaver but it's out of date and the person that created it is not maintaining it any more.   I would like to recreate it but I don't know how to get started.   What tools would I need to create an extension that I can package as a .mxp file and enable through Adobe Extension manager?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old list (from 2006 I believe) I found but might contain helpful information, not sure if all the links work or not and I hope some of it will be updated when you go to the pages. Hopefully this can provide a starting point. Also check out the [Adobe Forums](http://forums.adobe.com/index.jspa) (where this info came from)

Danilo Celic has prepared a list ( below ) of helpful links for those
interested in learning how to create extensions.

MX04:
Help > Extensions > Extending Dreamweaver
and
Help > Extensions > API Reference
and
Help > Extensions > Creating and Submitting

tutorials:
You can try Colm Gallaghers step by step tutorial on how to make a simple
Dreamweaver Object extension.
http://www.dwfaq.com/Tutorials/Extensions/simple_object.asp

http://www.dmxzone.com/showDetail.asp?TypeId=28&NewsId=5059
(20 page tutorial - commercial)

livedocs as well:
http://livedocs.macromedia.com/dreamweaver/mx2004/index.html

Dreamweaver MX 2004 SDK (includes MXI format for DWMX 2004):
http://www.macromedia.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?view=sn121&extid. ..

MXI File Format for DWMX 2004:
http://download.macromedia.com/pub/dw_exchange/mxi_file_format.pdf

MXI File format for DWMX and earlier:
http://download.macromedia.com/pub/dw_exchange/mxi_file_format.pdf

Books (dedicated):
Building Dreamweaver 4 and Dreamweaver UltraDev 4 Extension
Tom Muck and Ray West
http://basic-ultradev.com/building_extensions/index.asp

Dreamweaver MX Extensions
Laura Gutman
[http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/tg/detail/-/0735711828/qid=10686781](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735711828). ..

Covers extending:
Dreamweaver MX The Complete Reference
Ray West and Tom Muck
[http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0072195142/basicultradev-20](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0072195142)

Dreamweaver MX 2004 The Complete Reference
Ray West and Tom Muck
http://dwteam.com/tcr/

Beyond Dreamweaver
Joseph Lowrey
[http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/tg/detail/-/0789727404/qid=10686785](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0789727404). ..

Plus, always good to see what others have done. Visit the Exchange and
look at as many as you can:
http://www.macromedia.com/exchange/

Lists of DW extension developer sites:
http://www.dwfaq.com/Resources/Extensions/default.asp
http://www.felixone.it/extensions/mext.asp

Danilo also writes for: http://www.communitymx.com/ He has a few
extension related articles there (commercial site).